# Stackoverflow's Search feature differentiates Tag based from string based search with JS disabled

Tags: javascript, get

Well, I thought stackoverflow making a request based on Tags given within `[]` from String based search using javascript.

But, it works with JS disabled. If its just a `GET` request - how/why does it change with what is entered. If its not controlled by JS, then every request should be a `string based GET request`.

The question I have is "How to change the Type of request - Search based GET `search?q=xyz`  or tag based `/tagged/xyz` without using Javascript"?

Might be a silly question,beginner.

Comment: How to change the type of request without `Javascript`?. I thought they were doing it using `window.location` after parsing the entered text ( I was wrong as it works with JS disabled).

Comment: Read up about all the attributes a `<form>` element has.

Comment: deceze : Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Vivek: I voted to mode this question to [meta.stacjoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Questions about stackoverflow itself belong there.

Comment: @missingno — It's not really well expressed, but the question is "How do I achieve X? You can find an example of X on StackOverflow." It isn't a meta question.

Comment: You have 1.5k rep and don't know about meta?

Comment: I know about meta. I dont necessarily want to know about stackoverflow. I want to know how to grammatically achieve this, as an example - Stackoverflow's search feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag based search is built with plain hyperlinks:

```
<a href="/questions/tagged/get" class="post-tag" title="" rel="tag">get</a>
```

Since there is no form, and no user input, there is no query string generated. Since links are a basic part of HTML, no JavaScript is needed.

---

Update based on a comment:

It seems you are asking about what happens when the regular search form is used to search for something that is also a tag.

This can be achieved by the following server side logic:

```
IF search phrase is 1 word long
AND search phrase matches a tag_name in the tags database table
THEN issue HTTP 301 with Location: http://example.com/questions/tagged/ + search phrase
```

Comment: With stackoverflow, there is a `FORM` and its a normal `GET` request to `/search`. Is the tag based getting redirected from the server end?

Comment: I just wanted to know whether you could send seperate requests based on entered text with plain HTML elements.From your answer - its a server side logic and not from the client side, I think I got my answer. :D